# Sending a List to View to iterate over

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried searching SO, but maybe I'm not using the right search terms.

Basically, I first need to generate a list in my controller that would contain something like this:

```
Item 1: name = 'cat', category = 'animal'
Item 2: name = 'dog', category = 'animal'
Item 3: name = 'tulip', category = 'plant'
```

And so on.  So when I get to my view I can do a:

```
@foreach (item in list)
{
    if (category == "animal")
    {
        @item.name<br />
    }
}
```

How do I build the list in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you build any list.  Let's say you have a class defining your items and we'll call it `MyModel`.  (In this case I'll assume it has string properties `Name` and `Category`.)  Then you'd build a list of that object:

```
var models = new List<MyModel>();
```

And you can add any number of items you like to that list:

```
models.Add(new MyModel { Name = "Cat", Category = "Animal" });
models.Add(...);
// etc.
```

Then send it to the view:

```
return View(models);
```

In the view you'd declare that as your model type:

```
@model List<MyModel>
```

And can then iterate over it in the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Category == "animal")
    {
        @item.Name<br />
    }
}
```

A `List<T>` is no different from any other model type.  You can build one and send it to your view like any other model.

---

**Edit:** For the purpose of this example, the `MyModel` class was:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Naturally, you'll want to use a more meaningful name than `MyModel`.

Comment: This is giving me an error.  "The type or namespace MyModel could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?"

Comment: @yondaimehokage: Well, you'd use whatever name *your model* actually is.  Note the first couple sentences in this answer.  If you don't have a class, just define one for your needs.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do that?  I know how to do if if there is a database.

Comment: @yondaimehokage: I've added a sample class definition to the answer.  Honestly, given the questions you're asking you should *really* start with some introductory tutorials on C# and ASP.NET MVC.  You're not going to get far without knowing how to make a class or a list.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!  I'm still new at all this, and I appreciate it!